# polymorphism has been lost with casting

Tags: java

I have a class named `Student` and subclass called `AthleteStudent`:

```
public class Student {

    protected String name;
    protected String age;

    public void hello () {
        system.out.println("Hello I'm Student");
    }

}

public class AthleteStudent extends Student  {

    protected String sport;

    public void hello () {
        system.out.println("Hello I'm AthleteStudent");
    }

    public void changeDepartement() {
        .....
    }

}
```

Now let's take these test cases:

```
AthleteStudent ats = new AthleteStudent("test", 22, "Karate");
Student std;

std = ats;  // upcasting OK
/* ats and std point to the same object, i.e AthleteStudent */

ats.hello(); /* Hello I'm AthleteStudent => polymorphism OK */
std.hello(); /* Hello I'm AthleteStudent => polymorphism OK */
```

What I do not understand here is this one:

Even though `std` references a `AthleteStudent` I cannot access the method `changeDepartement()`.

```
std.changeDepartement(); // Doesn't work
```

Only when we cast this object like this one it works

```
((AthleteStudent) std).changeDepartement(); // OK
```

Why we need to force `std` to be an `AthleteStudent` object knowing that it is treated as a `AthleteStudent` object? With the first example, `std.hello()` prints the one from `AthleteStudent` implementation without problems.

Comment: simply , You can NOT cast objects in Java. however , You can cast references in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a loss of polymorphism.  This is a lack of [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079785/whats-an-example-of-duck-typing-in-java).  When the compiler, statically, only knows that it's a `Student` it wont allow you to call non `Student` methods.  Even though you know that, at run time, it will be available the static typing system of java says no.  Other languages have duck typing that wouldn't care.  Java isn't one of them.

Comment: thank you, i understand now why this problem take place

Answer (score 4):

`std` is of type `Student`, and it may hold refrences to objects that are not an `AthleteStudent`. Therefore, you can't call `std.changeDepartement()` without an explicit cast to `AthleteStudent`.