# What does `new Class<?>[] {}` mean?

Tags: java

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1079799

> Java is by design not fit for duck typing. The way you might choose to
>   do it is reflection:
>
> ```
> public void doSomething(Object obj) throws Exception {
>
>     obj.getClass().getMethod("getName", new Class<?>[] {}).invoke(obj);
> }
> ```

What does `new Class<?>[] {}` mean? Thanks.

Comment: same thing as `new Class<?>[0]` ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That creates an empty array of type `Class<?>` (which is a wild card capture of `Class`es). The array created is explicitly of length `0`. Which indicates that `getName` takes no arguments (if it took arguments, the array would need to contain the appropriate classes to match the type signature).

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what `{}` mean?

Comment: @Ben A zero length array initializer. `String[] arr = new String[] {"a"};` ... or `String[] arr = new String[] {};` (for an empty array) *or* `new String[0];` (for the same).